# How to call something after completion of nested subscriptions in typescript/rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

So I have to **create some user which on succession on which I have to create 2 different entities as well**. So it is something like this.

```
this.userRepository.saveAsNew(user).subscribe((user: User) => {
   user.addEntity1(Entity1).subscribe((entity1: EntityClass) => {},
         (err) => {
        this.isError = true;
        //show error}
         );
        user.addEntity2(entity2).subscribe(() => {},
          (err) => {
        this.isError = true;
        // do something
});
      }
    },
      (err) => {
        this.isError = true;
        // do something
      });

if (!this.Error){
//show success creation of all three entities
}
```

now the problem is that since **Error is defined false by default and when first subscription runs it is false and it shows success even when it is failure**. **So in short I want to execute this last if statement after I have gone through all the three subscriptions**. I can do this with putting callback on the outer subscription but I think that over complicates this whole thing. Is there any better approach to this?

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid nested subscriptions. Instead you could use higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map between observables.
2. Use RxJS `forkJoin` function to trigger multiple independent observables in parallel.

```js
this.userRepository.saveAsNew(user).pipe(
  switchMap((user: User) => 
    forkJoin([                         // <-- begin `forkJoin` array
      user.addEntity1(Entity1).pipe(
        catchError((error: any) => {
          // do something on error
          return throwError(error);
        })
      ), 
      user.addEntity2(entity2).pipe(
        catchError((error: any) => {
          // do something on error
          return throwError(error);
        })
      )
    ])                                // <-- end `forkJoin` array
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {

  },
  error: (error: any) => {

  },
  complete: () => {
    // do something when all observables are complete
    // show success creation of all three entities
  }
});
```

Comment: I would like to ask 3 follow up questions. 

1. it says that: tslint: forkJoin is deprecated: Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead how will that change this?

2. I also have to delete everything that has been created if error occurs. i.e; user and two entities will have to be deleted in case of error in any of the call.

3. entity1 was actually an array on which i was looping through previously. I can try to make multiplePost call in the request handler now and pass entity1 as an array now but is there any better solution than this. 
Lastly thank you so much! :D

Comment: @MuhammadDaniyalDanish: **1.** I've edited the answer to pass array parameter instead of multiple parameters. Please check if the deprecation error is solved now. **2.** How do you delete the entities? Are they HTTP requests? If so it could be returned from the `catchError` blocks. **3.** Looping over subscription could also be mitigated using `forkJoin`. But you'd have to show how you loop at the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael. **1**. The depreciation error is not there anymore.  **2**. These are all HTTP requests and I use DELETE to delete them. **3**. What I mean was Entity1 for example is array. So previously I used to loop over this array under the **User subscription (parent subscription)** and in that loop I used to call 
user.addEntity1(entityItem) . Not a good way I know, but just wondering if something like this is possible with current implementation?